# Using UIScrollView, UIImageView and Zooming with a single code for different views

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, uiimageview, zooming

I am very new to programming. I am currently developing an iOS app that uses UIButtons to access different `UIViews`. Each one contains a `UIScrollView` containing a `UIImageView`.
The purpose is to have a zoomable, scrollable and panable picture.
I found a very good example of how to do all of these, but the code declares an image with @
so I would have to create several `UIViews` and generate code for each to manage the specific `UIImage` (because all have different names) and `UIScroll`. It is not practical. What I need is to have a single `UIViewContoller` for different views and a single code that handles the views with different pictures.

This is the code that sets up the image to scroll & zoom and adds it to the scroll view (although I want to include the images visually through the storyboard and not by code).

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Title

    self.title = @"Image";

    // Set up the image to scroll & zoom and add it to the scroll view

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"photo1.png"];

    self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];

    self.imageView.frame = (CGRect){.origin=CGPointMake(0.0f, 0.0f), .size=image.size};

    [self.scrollView addSubview:self.imageView];
```

Please help!!

Thank you.

Comment: Can you show your IBAction function that gets called when the button is pushed? That is probably where you wil l want to change the UIImage in the view controller, unless I misunderstand your intent.